# category of vector bundles with connections and its K-theory

Tags: vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology, connections

For the category of Hermitian vector bundles with unitary connections, an object is (of course) a Hermitian vector bundle with a Hermitian metric and a unitary connection $(E, g^E, \nabla^E)$. For morphisms, one version I have seen is the following: for any two objects $(E, g^E, \nabla^E)$ and $(F, g^F, \nabla^F)$, a morphism is a bundle homomorphism $T:E\to F$ satisfying $g^E=T^*g^F$ and $T\circ\nabla^E=\nabla^F\circ T$. The latter condition means $T(\nabla^Es)=\nabla^F(T(s))$ for any section $s\in\Gamma(X, E)$. The other version of morphisms I have seen only involves the condition with the Hermitian metrics, and no condition with the unitary connections. In both of these categories, a morphism is an isomorphism if the bundle homomorphism is an isomorphism.

I am wondering how much do the $K$-theory of these categories differ? I have seen in a paper that the $K$-theory of the latter category, i.e. the morphisms have nothing to do with the connections, is isomorphic to topological $K$-theory. However, if we consider the $K$-theory of the former category, is it the same (isomorphic) to topological $K$-theory? If not, "how much" do they differ?

Comment: One relevant paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4935v1, which constructs differential K-theory from vector bundles with connection using a variant of group completion.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks for mentioning this paper. If I have not overlooked, it seems Simons and Sullivan do not impose any relations on the morphisms in both cases: whether the connections are unitary or not. However, this time I am not working with differential K-theory; in their setting it means I don't want an equivalence class of connections defined in terms of the Chern-Simons form.